# How to identify a line in a large text file, read values from line below, and save them to workspace

Tags: matlab, text-files

I have a large text file (~7000 lines) and am trying to write a script to pull specific values from this file.

The text file is formatted in a way, such that when a line starts with a keyword "Node", then the two values I want to write to the workspace are located 2 lines below this line seperated by several spaces.

So far I've managed to write a loop that goes through the text file line by line, and recognizes the keyword "Node" mentioned above - the problem is I can't use the strfind function on the actual value I need to write to the workspace because the nodal ID is not consistent and cannot be saved as a pattern.

```
fin = fopen(fullfile('textfile.txt'), 'r');
tLine = fgets(fin);
while ischar(tLine)
   if strfind(tLine, 'Node')
```

I can define a variable inside the last 'if' statement which saves any indexed part of the current tLine to a variable, but I need to grab the values which are two lines below the current line...

Comment: After your `if` statement is triggered, just repeat the statement `tLine = fgets(fin);` twice (until you capture the line of interest), then parse the values from this line.

Comment: This did what I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
fin = fopen(fullfile('textfile.txt'), 'r');

while ~feof(fin) %Use this to loop until the end of file:
   tLine = fgets(fin);
   if strfind(tLine, 'Node')
       if(strcmp(tLine[1:4],'Node')) % check if this line starts with 'Node' 
           fgets(fin); %Skip one line
           usable_line = fgets(fin); 
           [values, num_values] = sscanf(usable_line, '%f %f'); 
       end
   end
 end
```

See `doc sscanf` to check appropriate format.